# How to host a Vue3 vite base app by a specific path

Tags: vue.js, nginx, vite

I developed a Vue3/vite app and want to host it on server through NGINX on a path

example.com/auth

in nginx in available sites I have a location

```
location /auth {
                rewrite /auth/(.*) /$1  break;

                proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5143;
                proxy_redirect          off;
                proxy_set_header        Host            $host;
                proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  }
```

but then app starts in browser I see that the /auth path is not used but instead GET goes directly path /

GET xxx.westeurope.cloudapp.azure.com/@vite/client

instead

GET xxx.westeurope.cloudapp.azure.com/ ***auth*** /@vite/client

How to host a vue3 app behind a path /auth?

Comment: Did you look into the [Vite Config options](https://vitejs.dev/config/shared-options.html#base)? If I get your question right, you need to set the `base` option to `/auth`.

Comment: I have set it and I can reach main page of my app but all other paths do not work https://docs.google.com/document/d/1NftIDyESzPqepYLxtS1cuY1ycq0gniJw_L_En8wZlyY/edit

Comment: True, this does not work, You can try to use `base: ''` The question is, where your assets are published. Are they published on `/auth/...`?

Comment: Looking into your doc, it seems like this error is not related to the vite build. You get a `404` error, which might be, that the server cannot find the path, right?

Answer (score 0):

The bug was in nginx location

instead

```
rewrite /auth/(.*) /$1  break;
```

I have

```
rewrite /(.*) /$1  break;
```

and routing is now working